# in python function have arguments object like javascript function arguments?

Tags: javascript, python

In JavaScript I can use `arguments` in a function like:

```
function a (){
   console.log(arguments);
}

a(1,2,3,4,5,6) // Arguments(6) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, callee: ƒ, 
                Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ]
```

Do functions in Python have an object like JavaScript's arguments?

I tried to use `arguments` in python (like in JavaScript) but I am getting an error,
maybe there is an object in python but it is not called 'arguments'?

How can I get all the arguments of a function in python ?

Answer (score 4):

In Python to have access to arguments like in JS you would do following:

```
def funcA(*args):
   print(args)
```

You can use any name you want in place of `args`

```
funcA(1,2,3) # prints (1, 2, 3)
```